# How to vectorize function operating on two pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes; here are some smaller examples of what they look like:

```
utils = pd.DataFrame({'A1L1': [-0.42, 0.13, 1.56],
                      'A1L2': [-0.21, -0.01, 0.74],
                      'A1L3': [0.63, -0.12, -2.30],
                      'A2L1': [-0.63, 0.42, 0.33],
                      'A2L2': [0.63, -0.42, -0.33],
                      'A3L1': [-0.10, -0.34, 0.23],
                      'A3L2': [0.10, 0.34, -0.23],
                      'weight': [1.1, 0.9, 1.0],
                      'others': [4.23, 5.21, 4.88]})

settings = pd.DataFrame({0: [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                         1: [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                         2: [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]})
```

In my actual situation, the `utils` dataframe has more sets of A_L_ variables and 1,000 rows. The `settings` dataframe has more columns (one for each set of A columns in the `utils` dataframe) and 460,000 rows.

There's a function I want to perform for every row of the `settings` dataframe that depends on the `utils` dataframe.

First, I want to pull the L columns from `utils` that correspond to each column in `settings`; what I mean by that is that if the value of column 0 is 1, I should pull the A1L1 column. If the value of column 0 is 3, I should pull the A1L3 column. If the value of column 2 is 1, I should pull the A3L1 column.

Then, I want to sum those columns for each row, exponentiate that sum, divide the exponentiated sum by itself + the "others" column, multiply that result by the "weight" column and sum it, and finally divide by the sum of the "weight" column. Here's the function I've written to do that for one row of the `settings` dataframe:

```
def pref_share(row, df, weight, others):
    # Get names of attribute/level pairs
    var_names = "A" + (pd.Series(row).index+1).astype(str) + "L" + pd.Series(row).astype(str)

    # Compute share
    share = ((np.exp(df[var_names].sum(axis=1))/ \
              (np.exp(df[var_names].sum(axis=1)) + df[others].values)) \
             *df[weight]).sum(axis=0) / df[weight].sum(axis=0)
    return share
```

To get this calculated for every row in `settings`, I'm using `.apply()` with a lambda to apply it to the settings dataframe:

```
settings["share"] = settings.apply(lambda row: pref_share(row, utils, "weight", "others"), axis=1)
```

Putting all of the mathematical operations in one line did help with the speed, cutting it in about half from where it originally was, but it still takes about 45 minutes to run. I'm thinking that if I could find a way to vectorize such that I don't have to use `.apply()`, that might help. I also came across some answers referring to the numba module, but it seems like it won't accept pandas dataframes, so I think that might be out as an option.